# Erro codigo (Python, Pandas e Excel)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Fiz um código para pegar a hora e o dia da semana e assim pega na célula da planilha do excel e deveria me informar, mas está dando errado na hora de pegar, além disso na terça (incicaçao ES) dá erro.

Um exemplo de erro é: hoje é quarta-feira 12:53, era para ser almoço mas ele diz que o valor é "estuda Historia".

A variável da coluna e linha está dando o valor certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import pandas as pd #importa para mecher no excel
from datetime import date #importa semna
from datetime import datetime #importa data

for nu in range(10000000000): #repete
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------") #separa só estetico
    hj = date.today() #pega o dia de hoje
    dias = ('Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado', 'Domingo') #lista dos dias
    print ("Hoje é", dias[hj.weekday()]) #fala que dia da semana é
    x = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\rotina p.xlsx") #le a planilha
    semana = dias[hj.weekday()]  #Salva que dia da semana é

    minuto = datetime.today().minute #pega o minuto
    hora = datetime.today().hour #pega a hora

    #SE o dia for tal ele poe o nome da prmeira linha para pega a coluna
    if(semana == 'Segunda-feira'): 
        su = "AS"
    elif(semana == 'Terça-feira'):
       su = "ES"
    elif(semana == 'Quarta-feira'):
       su = "IS"
    elif(semana == 'Quinta-feira'):
        su = "OS"
    elif(semana == 'Sexta-feira'):
        su = "US"       
    elif(semana == 'Sábado'):
        su = "AO"
    elif(semana == 'Domingo'): 
        su = "AOS"

    #Ve se é antes ou depois de 30 minutos
    if(minuto >= 0 and minuto <= 30):
        print("antes dos 30")
        ates = True
    else:
        print("depois dos 30")
        ates = False

    #Fala que horas são
    if(hora == 7):
        print("agora são 7 horas")
    elif(hora == 8):
        print("agora são 8 horas")
    elif(hora == 9):
        print("agora são 9 horas")
    elif(hora == 10):
        print("agora são 10 horas")
    elif(hora == 11):
        print("agora são 11 horas")
    elif(hora == 12):
        print("agora são 12 horas")
    elif(hora == 13):
        print("agora são 13 horas")
    elif(hora == 14):
        print("agora são 14 horas")
    elif(hora == 15):
        print("agora são 15 horas")
    elif(hora == 16):
        print("agora são 16 horas")
    elif(hora == 17):
        print("agora são 17 horas")
    elif(hora == 18):
        print("agora são 18 horas")
    elif(hora == 19):
        print("agora são 19 horas")
    elif(hora == 20):
        print("agora são 20 horas")
    elif(hora == 21):
        print("agora são 21 horas")
    elif(hora == 22):
        print("agora são 22 horas")
    elif(hora == 23):
        print("agora são 23 horas")
    elif(hora == 24):
        print("agora são 24 horas")

    #Pega a hora
    if(hora == 7 and ates == False):
        cel = 3
    elif(hora == 8 and ates == True):
        cel=4
    elif(hora == 8 and ates == False):
        cel=5
    elif(hora == 9 and ates == True):
        cel=6
    elif(hora == 9 and ates == False):
        cel=7
    elif(hora == 10 and ates == True):
        cel=8
    elif(hora == 10 and ates == False):
        cel=9
    elif(hora == 11 and ates == True):
        cel=10
    elif(hora == 11 and ates == False):
        cel=11
    elif(hora == 12 and ates == True):
        cel=12
    elif(hora == 12 and ates == False):
        cel=13
    elif(hora == 13 and ates == True):
        cel=14
    elif(hora == 13 and ates == False):
        cel=15
    elif(hora == 14 and ates == True):
        cel=16
    elif(hora == 14 and ates == False):
        cel=17
    elif(hora == 15 and ates == True):
        cel = 18
    elif(hora == 15 and ates == False):
        cel = 19
    elif(hora == 16 and ates == True):
        cel = 20
    elif(hora == 16 and ates == False):
        cel = 21
    elif(hora == 17 and ates == True):
        cel = 22
    elif(hora == 17 and ates == False):
        cel = 23
    elif(hora == 18 and ates == True):
        cel = 24
    elif(hora == 18 and ates == False):
        cel = 25
    elif(hora == 19 and ates == True):
        cel = 26
    elif(hora == 19 and ates == False):
        cel = 27
    elif(hora == 20 and ates == True):
        cel = 28
    elif(hora == 20 and ates == False):
        cel = 29
    elif(hora == 21 and ates == True):
        cel = 30
    elif(hora == 21 and ates == False):
        cel = 31
    elif(hora == 22 and ates == True):
        cel = 32
    elif(hora == 22 and ates == False):
        cel = 33
    elif(hora == 23 and ates == True):
        cel = 34
    elif(hora == 23 and ates == False):
        cel = 35
    elif(hora == 24 and ates == True):
        cel = 36

    print(cel,su) #escreve a celula e coluna
    print(x[su][cel]) #printa a celula
```

Comment: Não mexo muito com Pandas então não posso opinar sobre o erro, mas sobre o restante do código, dá pra simplificar **bastante** coisa, principalmente eliminar este monte de `if`/`elif`, veja: https://repl.it/repls/PleasedBlandGames

Comment: Obrigado pela simplificaçao, eu sou meio novo com o python então só conhecia esse metodo

Comment: Tentei refazer a parte do panda ele ta pegando a celula  2 acima (o mesmo erro) mesmo a celula estando certo para resolver temporariamente eu pus cel = cel - 2 e ai ele pega o valor certo